# Print the currently viewed page in Google Chrome PDF viewer

Tags: google-chrome, pdf

When I'm viewing a large PDF document in Google Chrome, I often need to print a specific page, but I don't see an option to print the current page. Is it possible to print the page that I'm viewing in Chrome?