# pdf - Get current page number in Google Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, pdf

In Google Chrome, is it possible to get the current page number of a pdf document (the page that I'm viewing)? I have a document that is over 100 pages long, and I can't find the currently viewed page number anywhere.

Comment: I guess you want to do this so you can [print the currently viewed page](http://superuser.com/questions/485696/print-the-currently-viewed-page-in-google-chrome-pdf-viewer)? Is there a Print Preview option you can use that perhaps displays page numbers?

Comment: @Karan Yes, that's one reason why it would be useful to obtain the current page, but it's not the only reason. These are distinct questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @Karan says, select the print button and in the print preview screen you will notice a hovering tooltip by the scroll bar that indicates the current page.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't notice this before. Is it possible to quickly jump to a specific page on the print preview screen?

Comment: There's only one problem with this: When I click "Print", the print preview page shows the first page instead of the page that I was viewing. When I'm viewing a document with over 100 pages, this makes it very difficult to find the page that I was viewing.

Comment: @AndersonGreen If you type a page number in the Pages section it jumps directly to the page.

Comment: Where can I find the pages section?

Comment: @AndersonGreen On the left side of the screen. It says **Pages** with a radio button for **All** or a radio button for an input box with "eg. 1-5, 8, 11-13". If you put the the page number in the input box, the PDF will jump to said page.

Comment: Report the issue by opening a PDF file, then click on Chrome -> Tools -> report an issue (or go to chrome://feedback/?session_id=1&tab_index=1&description=&categoryTag=) and explain your problem. More reports will result in Google taking this problem seriously.

Comment: @VianEsterhuizen It actually doesn't answer the question entirely - pressing the "Print" button simply jumps to the first page of the document, instead of jumping to the currently viewed page. Due to this bug, it seems that there's no easy way to obtain the current page number in a multi-page document.

Comment: @AndersonGreen That's a valid point. You can unmark it, it definitely doesn't answer the question unless you just view the document in print view from the start. It is strange that Chrome has the feature in print preview but not PDF viewer though.